# Integrate message: can't prove Integration limits are real

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I'm working on solving differential equations through Fourier series, I made a function to help me calculate the coefficients that looks like this:

```
bn[α_, T_, f_] := (2/T)*Integrate[f*Sin[((2*Pi*n)/T)*t], {t, α, T + α}]
```

And it was workng pretty well, until I tried to evaluate this:

```
bn[0, L, Piecewise[{{0, 0 < t < L/3}, {w, L/3 < t < 2*(L/3)}, {0, 2*(L/3) < t < L}}]]
```

And it gives me the error:

> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {L} are real. Adding assumptions may help. >>

Any idea on what is causing/how to avoid the error? I tried using assumptions, but I guess I'm doing it wrong because it doens't help.

```
bn[α_, T_, f_] := 
  Integrate[(2/T)*f*Sin[((2*Pi*n)/T)*t], {t, α, α + T}, Assumptions -> Element[T, Reals]]
```

#### Edit

You mean enter the code like it is now? Sorry for the inconvenience, but the advanced help for the site sort of suggested that I used LaTeX.

Comment: I changed the format as you suggested. I think... Is it good now?

Comment: Thanks for the code addition. It does works well for non-piecewise defined functions `f`. I will pick at this later. Thanks for the post and the edit. You will get response in time I expect. My initial thought is to add code to deal with the piecewise defined cases in pieces.

Comment: The problem is that it works for functions that have numeric limits such as:

   `bn[-\[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Piecewise] {   {-\[Pi], -\[Pi] < t < 0},   {\[Pi], 0 < t < \[Pi]}  }]`

It does give me the expected result, I get stuck when I try to use variable periods `T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bn[a_, T_, f_] := 2/T Integrate[f Sin[(2 π n)/T t], {t, a, T + a},  Assumptions -> T ∈ Reals]
bn[0, L, Piecewise[{{0, 0 < t < L/3}, {w, L/3 < t < 2 L/3}, {0, 2 L/3 < t < L}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't know if I'm interpreting that correctly:

The output says that for any L>0, the result would be the one on the top left, times 2/L, right?

Comment: @FernandoContreras Yes, run it. The result is a Piecewise function. Take a look at the Piecewise[] doc page

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at the Piecewise doc, however the result seems odd. Since I couldn't let really stop working I solved it by hand and I get a completely different result. I'll get back at you when I figure out the problem.

Comment: @FernandoContreras Ok. The result seems good to me AFAIS

Comment: Ok, I analyzed the results I got in paper vs the code vs step by step in mathematica. Your answer is correct, as it makes the code work, however it still gives me a different result from the one that I'm getting on paper (and my book agrees with). Seems like the problem has to do with the Integration itself, not the piecewise. I suppose it has to do with assumptions I'm making that mathematica isn't, but I don't know why. It'd boil down to an integrate of:

`C Integrate[Sin[D t],{t,L/3,2L3]`

With C, and D being constants related to the weight distributed over a stick of length L.